# Java web application model - should it contain an attribute that holds the choices for a foreign key?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web-applications

I have two database tables.
One table stores data for a `commitment` that a supervisor is responsible for.
The other is a lookup table of available `programs`.  The `program` primary key is a foreign key in the `commitment` table (A commitment is against a particular funded program).

I have two Javabean objects that represent these tables, I think they are called DTO?? Anyways....

Now in my jsp view (for editing or inserting a commitment), I don't want users to see or have to enter the primary key to the program, but instead would rather they use a select pull down that shows the resolved program name with the fk id as the select option value.

My question is:
Should I be passing two attributes in the request - 'commitment' which represents the single row record in the db of that specific commitment (if editing) and the `programList` a list of available prgrams that I iterate over to display in a pull down??

Or should I modify my commitment DTO and make it have an attribute that can store a list of available programs (as program DTO's) so that then I'd only need to pass in the `commitment` DTO in a request attribute to my view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach is more self-documenting. A commitment is tied to a specific program, not to multiple programs. Having a `List<Program>` in `Commitment` is therefore confusing to others (and also to yourself when you look back one year later).

That said, if the `List<Program>` is application-wide (read: it's always the same list for every user/session), I'd just put it in the application scope rather than the request scope.

Comment: never thought of the application scope.  I should add that a user could add to the list of programs on another screen.  List is the same for all users but is dynamic and can change, albeit not very often.  Would this affect whether it could go in to the application scope?

Comment: Just alter the list in the application scope. It'll be reflected applicationwide.

Comment: I've accepted this answer based on BalusC's point of being sef-documenting.  I agree it, it doesn't muddy the waters.

Comment: You're welcome. The list being application wide is by the way one more reason to not put it in `Commitment`. It makes little sense to have multiple references to the very same list.

Comment: I know the systax to set it in application scope getServletContext().setAttribute("programList", programList);  but where is this implemented?  If a user adds, deletes or edits using CRUD functionality, what triggers the refresh of this application scope programList?

Comment: You don't need to refresh if you get hold of the same reference. Just obtain it from application scope by `getAttribute()` and alter it. That's all. All requests/sessions accesses the same reference anyway.

Comment: I'm still confused as to where I implement the establishment of the an application scope attribute (servlet, DAO, model??) Another thing, if the programList is retreived in a Static manner, wouldn't that mean I do not have multiple references and therefore no reason to put it in application scope, except that I hit the db everytime the list is referenced?

Comment: Use either `HttpServlet#init()` or `ServletContextListener#contextInitialized()`. As to your last concern: I don't understand it.